# Registering SQL Dependency again from onchange event

Tags: c#, sqldependency

i like to know is it right approach to registering SQL Dependency again from onchange event ?

one guy review my code and told me `registering everything again and again after each notification. As I can recall this will create a queue each time`

so i comment this code in onchange event

```
void OnDataChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            BBALogger.Write("PartIndexer Service OnDataChange called start", BBALogger.MsgType.Info);

            if (e.Source == SqlNotificationSource.Timeout)
            {
                BBALogger.Write("PartIndexer Service SqlNotificationSource.Timeout error", BBALogger.MsgType.Error);
                Environment.Exit(1);
            }
            else if (e.Source != SqlNotificationSource.Data)
            {
                BBALogger.Write("PartIndexer Service SqlNotificationSource.Data", BBALogger.MsgType.Error);
                Environment.Exit(1);
            }
            else if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
            {
                BBALogger.Write("PartIndexer Service Data changed detected", BBALogger.MsgType.Info);
            }
            else
            {
                BBALogger.Write(string.Format("Ignored change notification {0}/{1} ({2})", e.Type, e.Info, e.Source), BBALogger.MsgType.Warnings);
            }

            CallWebService();
            //((SqlDependency)sender).OnChange -= OnDataChange;
            //RegisterNotification();
        }
```

just see i comment this line

```
    //((SqlDependency)sender).OnChange -= OnDataChange;
    //RegisterNotification();
```

but after commenting i found onchange event is firing first time and it is not firing from second time.

guide me with right approach. here is my partial code

```
void OnDataChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    BBALogger.Write("PartIndexer Service OnDataChange called start", BBALogger.MsgType.Info);

    if (e.Source == SqlNotificationSource.Timeout)
    {
    BBALogger.Write("PartIndexer Service SqlNotificationSource.Timeout error", BBALogger.MsgType.Error);
    Environment.Exit(1);
    }
    else if (e.Source != SqlNotificationSource.Data)
    {
    BBALogger.Write("PartIndexer Service SqlNotificationSource.Data", BBALogger.MsgType.Error);
    Environment.Exit(1);
    }
    else if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
    {
    BBALogger.Write("PartIndexer Service Data changed detected", BBALogger.MsgType.Info);
    }
    else
    {
    BBALogger.Write(string.Format("Ignored change notification {0}/{1} ({2})", e.Type, e.Info, e.Source), BBALogger.MsgType.Warnings);
    }

    CallWebService();
    //((SqlDependency)sender).OnChange -= OnDataChange;
    //RegisterNotification();
}


private void RegisterNotification()
    {
        string tmpdata = "";
        BBALogger.Write("PartIndexer Service RegisterNotification called start", BBALogger.MsgType.Info);

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDependency.Stop(connectionString);
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);

        try
        {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ActivityDate FROM [dbo].tablename";
            dep = new SqlDependency(cmd);
            dep.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnDataChange);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            {
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                dr.Read();
                tmpdata = dr[0].ToString();
            }
            }
            dr.Dispose();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        BBALogger.Write("PartIndexer Service RegisterNotification Error "+ex.Message.ToString(), BBALogger.MsgType.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
        BBALogger.Write("PartIndexer Service RegisterNotification called end", BBALogger.MsgType.Info);

        }

}
```

i use Environment.Exit(1); to shutdown win service as a result it should restart automatically. thanks
thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/) re-subscription is the right approach for  changes monitoring in SQL server tables:

> Note how, similarly to the SqlNotification usage, the client is expected to **subscribe again** if it whishes to be further notified.

Even [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/144344/Query-Notification-using-SqlDependency-and-SqlCach) confusing example from CodePoject.com makes re-subscription (hidden in MessageModel.cs):

```
void notifier_NewMessage(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    // Indeed, the RegisterDependency call in the event hanler!
    this.LoadMessage(this.Notifier.RegisterDependency());
}
```

And take a look at the what the inventor [saying](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1904580/2013969) about it.

As I [told](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29787054/2013969) you before [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) has the problems with [behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29843706/sql-dependency-onchange-event-not-firing-every-time-c-sharp), [usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29781639/sql-dependency-and-data-refering-in-sql) and [memory leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511806/how-do-i-clean-sqldependency-from-sql-server-memory/). Try to use open source classes like [SqlDependencyEx](https://github.com/dyatchenko/ServiceBrokerListener/blob/master/ServiceBrokerListener/ServiceBrokerListener.Domain/SqlDependencyEx.cs). I solved a lot of problems using it.
With `SqlDependecyEx` you are able to monitor `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE` separately and receive **actual changed** data (`xml`) in the event args object. Hope this help.

Comment: i am interested to use SqlDependecyEx and here u said we can monitor INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE separately and receive actual changed data (xml) in the event args object but how......i need code sample of  SqlDependecyEx  to monitor INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE separately and also get the changed data in xml format. need a complete code.

Comment: @Mou Here are the full examples which you need: https://github.com/dyatchenko/ServiceBrokerListener/issues/5#issuecomment-96284037

Comment: i saw some time data is not getting populated in this system table `dm_qn_subscriptions`   `select * from sys.dm_qn_subscriptions`

Comment: anyone can tell me what could be the reason for which data is not populated some time in this system table `dm_qn_subscriptions` ? data is suppose to be inserted in this system dm_qn_subscriptions when data inserted or update in a specific table which is being monitor by sql dependency. let me know what could be the reason. thanks